# How to generate client access token for any client from controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

We can generate token using oauth work flow. [image]

But i want to generate the token internally from my own controller. How do we achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens) suggest, you can call your own oauth server to get the token.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

private function getClientToken() {
     $response = Http::asForm()->post(route('passport.token'),[
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
        'client_id' => 'client-id',
        'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
        'scope' => 'your-scope',
    ]);

    return $response->json()['access_token'];
}
```

Comment: This can be a hack but do you think its good to request to own endpoint and re-initiate whole request flow ?

Comment: This is not considered a hack, but the approach to getting tokens. Imagine you where getting client tokens from googles oauth provider. You would also be making Http calls. And the part of making a http call, should not at all be a performance problem or similar. Similar people understand oauth as http requests as it is defined in the oauth spec.

Comment: For any external service to connect , this endpoint is cool. but as i need to generate accessToken only, this is like adding a layer of http request to self. i don't feel this as good option.

Comment: @AnmupGiri - I am not sure why this answer was downvoted. However, this method is a good recommendation. Directly calling internal features can represent issues in the future. An HTTP call internally is extremely fast, and you do not need to worry about interface changes in the future.

Comment: To be honest you can think what ever you want off course, but if have had this solution running and churning out millions of user tokens without a problem :) internal http calls is not a problem

Comment: I was thinking of something like creating own JWT token for internal use. I went through the passport code. I found how they issue JWT there. I created a custom solution just to issue the token and everything else i will use laravel passport. what i felt is calling http internally also, recreates whole new app service container which is a load for memory and processing. Reason is, I dont want to waste resource.

Comment: If that does anything noticeably to your applications resources you got other problems